# How to insist that a textbox has a value

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a textbox on a form and a button on the same form. On the button click event I want to insist that the textbox has a value in the form of a Double. What I have so far is this -

```
 public double getUnitStake(Form frontpage)
    {

        double doubleresult=0;
        bool unitStake;

        foreach (Control c in frontpage.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Name == "tbUnitStake")
            {

                unitStake = double.TryParse( (c as TextBox).Text, out doubleresult);
                if (!unitStake)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    doubleresult=double.Parse((c as TextBox).Text);

                }



            }
        }


        return doubleresult;
    }
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out what to do if the double.tryparse method is false. What I want is the program execution to halt until a suitable value has been entered into the textbox. How can I achieve that please? Thanks for all and any help.

Comment: Oh, I should say that it maybe that the above approach is not the way to approach the problem, I just thought that it might help to show the code that I had thus far.

Comment: Please mark the answer yes if you got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you are validating the contents of a textbox. Therefore you can use the validating event of a TextBox Control. Optionally connect an errorProvider control to it to give special focus on the error (blinking exclamation mark). The "e.Cancel" statement will prevent you from doing anything else with your form until a double is entered.

```
   private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        double doubleresult = 0;

        bool result = Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out doubleresult);

        if (result)
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, string.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Must be a Double");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Right idea.  But be aware that this will not work when the user never set the focus to the control.

Comment: Hans this is indeed true. Implementing ValidateChildren on the button click event might help in overcoming this issue

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the complete requirements of your program.

You could disable the button by default. In the text change event of the text box, check if the value entered is a double.

Once you have verified that the value is indeed a double, then you could enable the button.
This way the program execution is halted by default, unless a double is entered.

Answer (score 0):

you just need TryParse yor value if your value not a double this method return you 0.0:

```
public double getUnitStake(Form frontpage)
{

    double doubleresult=0;


    foreach (Control c in frontpage.Controls)
    {
        if (c.Name == "tbUnitStake")
        {

            double.TryParse( (c as TextBox).Text, out doubleresult);
        }
    }


    return doubleresult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is fine except the following change**

```
 public double getUnitStake(Form frontpage)
{

    double doubleresult=0;
    bool unitStake;

    foreach (Control c in frontpage.Controls)
    {
        if (c.Name == "tbUnitStake")
        {

            unitStake = double.TryParse( (c as TextBox).Text, out doubleresult);
        }
    }


    return doubleresult;
}
```

you need not to parse the "doubleresult" again as the tryparse has already done it. You can use unitStake variable for further use.